# How to stop background style from overriding backgroundColor style of React inline-style?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Why does `background` override `backgroundColor` in React inline-style ?

In this example, the green background-color is not set, and so the background gradient which includes transparency fades into white, rather than green, in the transparent parts.

How can I stop this from happening so the transparency is useful?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor:"green", background: "radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0px 0px, rgb(230, 100, 101), transparent)"}}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

It works if I just set the css externally, but I need this to work in the react inline style because the css will be dynamic.

Comment: put background property before backgroundColor, the fact is that the codeFlow read for background after having readen for backgroundColor, hence probably it override what figures in your backgroundColor's space

Comment: This isn't a React thing. This is due to CSS specificity and it would be the same in a pure HTML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use multiple css rules targeting the same property, the last one wins overriding all previous ones. That is why the radial gradient was the only rule visible. Fortunately, it is possible to use [multiple css backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds), so you cant combine different backgrounds by just chaining all background definitions like shown below:

```
background: background1, background2, ..., backgroundn
```

Your example, modified to have both backgrounds, is shown in the snippet below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{background: "radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0px 0px, rgb(230, 100, 101), transparent), green"}}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `green` attribute after your gradient in `background`, and get rid of `backgroundColor` completely:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{background: "radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0px 0px, rgb(230, 100, 101), green)"}}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```